# Evaluate product of trace of two matrices

Tags: matrices, trace

I have a question. Let A be a positive semi-definite matrix, H be a positive definite matrix. Is the following inequality right: $Tr(AH).Tr(AH^{-1}) \geq (Tr(A))^2$?
I tried to take some concrete examples and always got the inequality above. If it's true, how can it be proved ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $H$ is positive definite, thus symmetric, it can be diagonalized, $H=QDQ^{-1}$ with $D$ diagonal matrix with positive entries.
Then
$$
tr(AH)tr(AH^{-1}) = tr(AQDQ^{-1})tr(AQD^{-1}Q^{-1})=tr(Q^{-1}AQD)tr(Q^{-1}AQD^{-1}).
$$
Set $B:=Q^{-1}AQ$. Then $tr(B)=tr(A)$.
Since $D$ is diagonal, we have
$$
tr(BD) = \sum_{i=1}^n b_{ii}d_{ii}.
$$
Defining $x:=sqrt(diag(B))=(\sqrt{b_{11}},\dots,\sqrt{b_{nn}})^T$ we can write 
$$
tr(BD)tr(BD^{-1}) =(x^TDx)(x^TD^{-1}x).
$$
From Cauchy-Schwarz inequality you get for every positiv definite matrix $M$
(check Kantorovich inequality)
$$
(x^Tx)^2  = (x^TM^{1/2}M^{-1/2}x)^2 \le (x^TMx)(x^TM^{-1}x)\quad \forall x.
$$
Apply this with $M:=D$, to get
$$
(x^TDx)(x^TD^{-1}x)\ge (x^Tx)^2  = tr(B)^2=tr(A)^2,
$$
and the inequality is proven.

Comment: It's wonderful. How can you explain why $b_{ii} \geq 0$ in your proof ?

Comment: $Q$ is orthogonal, hence $B$ is symmetric and positive definite as well

Answer (score 2):

A slightly shorter proof (but essentially the same proof as the one by @daw):
Apply Cauchy.-Schwarz on
$$ \operatorname{tr}(A) = \operatorname{tr}((H^{-1/2} A^{1/2}) (A^{1/2} H^{1/2})). $$

Comment: This is somehow the essence of my (longer) proof

Comment: @daw yes. It just hides many technical details of your proof. But it is shorter for those with little bit background.